# An elegant way to parse sexp

Tags: parsing, ocaml, s-expression

*sexp* is like this: `type sexp = Atom of string | List of sexp list`, e.g., `"((a b) ((c d) e) f)"`.

I have written a parser to parse a sexp string to the type:

```
let of_string s =
  let len = String.length s in
  let empty_buf () = Buffer.create 16 in
  let rec parse_atom buf i =
    if i >= len then failwith "cannot parse"
    else 
      match s.[i] with 
      | '(' -> failwith "cannot parse"
      | ')' -> Atom (Buffer.contents buf), i-1
      | ' ' -> Atom (Buffer.contents buf), i
      | c when i = len-1 -> (Buffer.add_char buf c; Atom (Buffer.contents buf), i)
      | c -> (Buffer.add_char buf c; parse_atom buf (i+1))
  and parse_list acc i =
    if i >= len || (i = len-1 && s.[i] <> ')') then failwith "cannot parse"
    else 
      match s.[i] with
      | ')' -> List (List.rev acc), i
      | '(' -> 
        let list, j = parse_list [] (i+1) in
        parse_list (list::acc) (j+1)
      | c -> 
        let atom, j = parse_atom (empty_buf()) i in
        parse_list (atom::acc) (j+1)
  in 
  if s.[0] <> '(' then
    let atom, j = parse_atom (empty_buf()) 0 in
    if j = len-1 then atom
    else failwith "cannot parse"
  else 
    let list, j = parse_list [] 1 in
    if j = len-1 then list
    else failwith "cannot parse"
```

But I think it is too verbose and ugly.

Can someone help me with an elegant way to write such a parser?

Actually, I always have problems in writing code of parser and what I could do only is write such a ugly one.

Any tricks for this kind of parsing? How to effectively deal with symbols, such as `(`, `)`,  that implies recursive parsing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a lexer+parser discipline to separate the details of lexical syntax (skipping spaces, mostly) from the actual grammar structure. That may seem overkill for such a simple grammar, but it's actually better as soon as the data you parse has the slightest chance of being wrong: you really want error location (and not to implement them yourself).

A technique that is easy and gives short parsers is to use stream parsers (using a Camlp4 extension for them described in the [Developping Applications with Objective Caml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/index.html) book); you may even get a lexer for free by using the [Genlex](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Genlex.html) module.

If you want to do really do it manually, as in your example above, here is my recommendation to have a nice parser structure. Have mutually recursive parsers, one for each category of your syntax, with the following interface:

- parsers take as input the index at which to start parsing
- they return a pair of the parsed value and the first index *not* part of the value
- nothing more

Your code does not respect this structure. For example, you parser for atoms will fail if it sees a `(`. That is not his role and responsibility: it should simply consider that this character is not part of the atom, and return the atom-parsed-so-far, indicating that this position is not in the atom anymore.

Here is a code example in this style for you grammar. I have split the parsers with accumulators in triples (`start_foo`, `parse_foo` and `finish_foo`) to factorize multiple start or return points, but that is only an implementation detail.

I have used a new feature of 4.02 just for fun, [match with exception](http://ocamllabs.github.io/compiler-hacking/2014/02/04/handler-case.html), instead of explicitly testing for the end of the string. It is of course trivial to revert to something less fancy.

Finally, the current parser does not fail if the valid expression ends before the end of the input, it only returns the end of the input on the side. That's helpful for testing but you would do it differently in "production", whatever that means.

```
let of_string str =
  let rec parse i =
    match str.[i] with
      | exception _ -> failwith "unfinished input"
      | ')' -> failwith "extraneous ')'"
      | ' ' -> parse (i+1)
      | '(' -> start_list (i+1)
      | _ -> start_atom i
  and start_list i = parse_list [] i
  and parse_list acc i =
    match str.[i] with
      | exception _ -> failwith "unfinished list"
      | ')' -> finish_list acc (i+1)
      | ' ' -> parse_list acc (i+1)
      | _ ->
        let elem, j = parse i in
        parse_list (elem :: acc) j
  and finish_list acc i =
    List (List.rev acc), i
  and start_atom i = parse_atom (Buffer.create 3) i
  and parse_atom acc i =
    match str.[i] with
      | exception _ -> finish_atom acc i
      | ')' | ' ' -> finish_atom acc i
      | _ -> parse_atom (Buffer.add_char acc str.[i]; acc) (i + 1)
  and finish_atom acc i =
    Atom (Buffer.contents acc), i
  in
  let result, rest = parse 0 in
  result, String.sub str rest (String.length str - rest)
```

Note that it is an error to reach the end of input when parsing a valid expression (you must have read at least one atom or list) or when parsing a list (you must have encountered the closing parenthesis), yet it is valid at the end of an atom.

This parser does not return location information. All real-world parsers should do so, and this is enough of a reason to use a lexer/parser approach (or your preferred monadic parser library) instead of doing it by hand. Returning location information here is not terribly difficult, though, just duplicate the `i` parameter into the index of the currently parsed character, on one hand, and the first index used for the current AST node, on the other; whenever you produce a result, the location is the pair (`first index`, `last valid index`).

Comment: If I am forced to do manually, should I simulate the process of lex + parse? I mean, e.g., for the sexp parser, should I first convert them to tokens, then do parse on the tokens?

Comment: could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891077/how-to-parse-a-string-to-a-regex-type-in-ocaml?noredirect=1#comment36784683_23891077?