# How to parse a string to a regex type in OCaml

Tags: regex, ocaml

We define a regex type like this:

```
type regex_t =
    | Empty_String
    | Char of char
    | Union of regex_t * regex_t 
    | Concat of regex_t * regex_t 
    | Star of regex_t
```

We want to write a function `string_to_regex: string -> regex_t`.

- The only char for `Empty_string` is 'E'
- The only chars for `Char` are 'a'..'z'
- '|' is for `Union`
- '*' is for `Star`
- `Concat` is assumed for continuous parsing.
- '(' / ')' have highest Precedence, then star, then concat, then union

For example,

`(a|E)*(a|b)` will be

```
Concat(Star(Union(Char 'a',Empty_String)),Union(Char 'a',Char 'b'))
```

---

How to implement `string_to_regex`?

Comment: This is just a parsing problem, right? I'd say gasche recently wrote you some excellent code that you can adapt.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Yes, I tried to learn from his code, but I don't think I get it or can adapt. This regex parsing is more complicated than sexp parsing. and I don't think I really get it.

Comment: gasche's solution is [recursive descent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). It's very easy to master. Start by writing a little grammar.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield but this regex parsing involves operators, does it fit recursive descent parsing?

Comment: You can build a compiler for a serious language using recursive descent. (The first Pascal compiler was written this way.) Yes, it will work for your RE language.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I mean what I am seeking for is raw parsing, not involving lex, parsing, etc

Comment: For an example of a raw parser, see my own implementation: https://github.com/youjinbou/dregexp/blob/master/src/regexp.ml . My data structure to represent regexp is roughly the same, except that I use a dedicated type for character classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ocamllex and menhir are wonderful tools to write lexers and parsers

**ast.mli**

```
type regex_t =
| Empty
| Char of char
| Concat of regex_t * regex_t
| Choice of regex_t * regex_t
| Star of regex_t
```

**lexer.mll**

```
{ open Parser }

rule token = parse
| ['a'-'z'] as c { CHAR c }
| 'E' { EMPTY }
| '*' { STAR }
| '|' { CHOICE }
| '(' { LPAR }
| ')' { RPAR }
| eof { EOF }
```

**parser.mly**

```
%{ open Ast %}

%token <char> CHAR
%token EMPTY STAR CHOICE LPAR RPAR CONCAT
%token EOF

%nonassoc LPAR EMPTY CHAR

%left CHOICE
%left STAR
%left CONCAT

%start main
%type <Ast.regex_t> main

%%

main: r = regex EOF { r }

regex:
| EMPTY { Empty }
| c = CHAR { Char c }
| LPAR r = regex RPAR { r }
| a = regex CHOICE b = regex { Choice(a, b) }
| r = regex STAR { Star r }
| a = regex b = regex { Concat(a, b) } %prec CONCAT
```

**main.ml**

```
open Ast

let rec format_regex = function
| Empty -> "Empty"
| Char c -> "Char " ^ String.make 1 c
| Concat(a, b) -> "Concat("^format_regex a^", "^format_regex b^")"
| Choice(a, b) -> "Choice("^format_regex a^", "^format_regex b^")"
| Star(a) -> "Star("^format_regex a^")"

let () =
  let s = read_line () in
  let r = Parser.main Lexer.token (Lexing.from_string s) in
  print_endline (format_regex r)
```

and to compile

```
ocamllex lexer.mll
menhir parser.mly
ocamlc -c ast.mli
ocamlc -c parser.mli
ocamlc -c parser.ml
ocamlc -c lexer.ml
ocamlc -c main.ml
ocamlc -o regex parser.cmo lexer.cmo main.cmo
```

and then

```
$ ./regex
(a|E)*(a|b)
Concat(Star(Choice(Char a, Empty)), Choice(Char a, Char b))
```

Comment: @JacksonTale (OP) I'm not sure what you're really looking for, but it's hard to beat this solution! Note that there is still non-trivial lexing to do even though your tokens are all 1 character long. I.e., you need to *categorize* them.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I am actually looking for a raw way to parse a string to the regex type, not using ocamllex and menhir

Comment: I have to say I don't see the point, but you can hack virtually any parsing problem using recursive descent.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I am doing this excise: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2010/cmsc330/p4/

Comment: you can use the same ideas. That is, a lexer to process 'tokens' of an input stream and then process that into your regular expression language just like the `parser.mly`. So you have, `input_channel -> token list`, and `token list -> regexp`. You can even make the channel processing lazy very easily.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Thomas is very complete, but actually the precedence of the operators is not correct: parsing `a|aa` will result in `Concat(Choice(Char a, Char a), Char a)`, namely equals `(a|a)a`. The [regular expression operators precedence](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Eaho/cs3261/Lectures/L3-Regular_Expressions.html#:%7E:text=The%20regular%2Dexpression%20operator%20star,precedence%20and%20is%20left%20associative.) requires that `a|aa = a|(aa)`, which should then result in `Choice(Char a, Concat(Char a, Char a))`. The problem is that the `CONCAT` token is a hack, and even if you specify `%left CHOICE` before `%left CONCAT` in the `parser.mly` file, this doesn't imply that the precedence will be respected. One possible solution is to perform [recursive descending parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20recursive,the%20nonterminals%20of%20the%20grammar.&text=A%20predictive%20parser%20runs%20in%20linear%20time.), effectively making the grammar unambiguous. If you want to use this approach you can modify `parser.mly` with:

```
%{ open Ast %}

%token <char> CHAR
%token EMPTY
%token STAR
%token CHOICE
%token LPAR
%token RPAR
%token EOF

%start main
%type <Ast.regex_t> main

%%

main: r = regex EOF { r }

regex:
| r = disjunction { r }

disjunction:
| a = disjunction CHOICE b = concat { Choice(a, b) }
| r = concat {r}

concat:
| a = concat b = repetition { Concat(a, b) } 
| r = repetition {r}

repetition:
| r = repetition STAR { Star r }
| r = atom { r }

atom:
| LPAR r = regex RPAR { r }
| c = CHAR { Char c }
| EMPTY { Empty }
```

This leads to no ambiguity (= no need to specify operators associativity and precedence) and will produce the correct result.